# increase message size quota

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, configuration

I get the following message when I run the application:
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="abc" connectionString="Data Source=xyz;Initial Catalog=abc;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abc;Password=abc"/>
  </connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true"/>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"/>
 <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
 <bindings>
 <basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="PictureBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" maxBufferSize="2000000">
<readerQuotas
maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
maxArrayLength="2147483647"
 maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
 </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="WCFservice.Service1Behavior">
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
</behavior>
<behavior name="">
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
<service behaviorConfiguration="WCFservice.Service1Behavior" name="WCFservice.Service1">
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PictureBinding" contract="WCFservice.IService1">
</endpoint>
 <endpoint address="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFservice.IService1">
</endpoint>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
 </service>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this configuration

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" 
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                 maxArrayLength="200000000"
                 maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

you can do it pragmatically too

```
BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
httpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
httpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
```